# php looping two arrays

Tags: php

```
$arr1 = array(
    1 => array(
        30 => 100
        31 => 800
    ),
    2 => array(
        30 => 200
        31 => 900
    ),
    3 => array(
        30 => 300
        31 => 100
    ),
    4 => array(
        30 => 400
        31 => 110
    ),
    5 => array(
        30 => 500
        31 => 120
    ),
    6 => array(
        30 => 600
        31 => 130
    ),
    7 => array(
        30 => 260
        31 => 140
    )
);
```

```
$arr2 = array(
    0 => array(
        id => 30  
    ),
    1 => array(
        id => 31          
    )
)
```

I need to loop through the $arr1 and insert in this fashion

```
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('30','1',100);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('30','2',200);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('30','3',300);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('30','4',300);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('30','5',500);
```

and so on

```
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('31','1',900);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('31','2',900);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('31','3',100);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('31','4',110);
INSERT INTO tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price) VALUES ('31','5',120);
```

and so on. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  foreach ($arr2 as $id)
  {
    foreach ($arr1 as $i => $v)
    {
        query("insert into tablename (option_value_id,duration_id,price)"
            . " values ('$id','$i',$v)");
    }
  }
```

Comment: @user286389 Two remarks: 1. PHP is very convenient when working with arrays (`foreach`, all arrays are *associative* (maps)). 2. You can edit your profile and set a decent user name (I apologize if 286389 has actually a meaning, and is number chosen by yourself :-)